# Show Grid As Static Height In JqGrid..?

Tags: jqgrid, grid

I have a grid that contain 25 records, in page size property i set to 10 records per page , then i will have 3 pages in the final page it displays only 5 rows, Here i want to show
10 rows. (First five records then next five as empty rows)
Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not full clear because you don't posted the JavaScript code which you use. Typically one use either

```js
rowNum: 10,
height: "auto"
```

or

```js
rowNum: 10,
height: 230, // 23px for a row
scrollOffset: 0
```

Comment: Thank U #Oleg..But height:"auto" didn't work for instead of i'm using manually give the height